# fontspec features not working correctly in floating environment

Tags: floats, luatex, fontspec

The fontspec properties seem to work not correctly inside a floating environment, if used with LuaLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
{
\fontspec[Color=FF0000]{DejaVu Sans}
This is a test for fontspec.
}

\begin{table}
{
\fontspec[Color=FF0000]{DejaVu Sans}
This is a test for fontspec.
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This little example works well with XeLaTeX, but compiled with LuaLaTeX Version beta-0.70.2 (TeX Live 2012), the text inside the table environment is printed black instead of red.

Is there some way to fix this behavior with LuaLaTeX? Using XeLaTeX is not really a workaround since I depend heavyly on LuaLaTeX's capabilities.

Comment: Works perfectly with TL2012 (LuaTeX, Version beta-0.71.0-2012080520 (rev 4356); fontspec.sty 2012/05/06 v2.2b).

Comment: I can replicate the problem using `fontspec` 2012/05/06 v2.2b and LuaTeX  Version beta-0.70.2-2012062819 which is the latest version available through normal channels I think.